# How to inject JSON coming from feeder inside body with gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a gatling scenario which

1. create a Http object
2. create a post request with a body
3. set up the scenario

I can inject a body from a JSON file containing this:

```
[{"id":"1"}]
```

At this point I have no problem. My question is on the second point. I want users to have theirs body feed with different id. So I think I have to use a feeder in order to set body for each user from a JSON Array. The JSON file that I use as feeder is like this:

```
[{
    "id":"1"},
    {"id":"2"},
    {"id":"3"},
    {"id":"4"},
    {"id":"5"},
    {"id":"6"},
    {"id":"7"},
    {"id":"8"},
    {"id":"9"},
    {"id":"10"},
    {"id":"11"},
    {"id":"12"},
    {"id":"13"}
]
```

I don't know the syntax to inject inside the body value coming from feeder. I have a fake body line in the code below, which doesn't work you bet, but I don't what should replace this line. The line has a comment:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.HeaderNames._
import io.gatling.http.request._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://localhost:8099")
    .headers(Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json"))
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")

  val feeder = jsonFile("src/test/resources/json/gatling/test.json")

  val scnPost = scenario("BasicSimulation")
    .feed(feeder)
    .exec(http("request_1")
      .post("/spring-test")
      //I have to replace this line...
      .body(RawFileBody("${.}"))
      .check(status.is(200)))

  setUp(
    scnPost.inject(constantUsersPerSec(3) during(3 seconds))
  ).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

Do you have any idea, how to inject JSON inside body from feeder?

Comment: Try `.body(StringBody("""{$id}"""))`

Comment: Hi, thank for the comment. I tried but it does not change anything. And in fact, I would like to inject inside body all the json. Not uniquely the id value.

Comment: For that you can get the `length` of your json and execute `.body()` within `for loop`